# problemas al ejecutar un proyecto .Net con Docker

Tags: .net, docker

Estoy tratando de seguir este tutorial:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#introduction
Para correr una aplicación .Net en Docker.

Sin embargo, al ejecutar el comando docker ps -a me aparece la siguiente salida:

```
"dotnet aspnetapp.dl…"   11 seconds ago      Exited (145) 8 seconds ago                         myapp
```

Alguien sabe el por qué de este error y como corregirlo, le estaría muy agradecido. Soy totalmente nuevo en Docker.

Nota extra:
La versión de Docker que estoy utilizando es la **18.03.0-ce**
El sistema operativo es CentOS 7
y la versión de .Net Core es la 2.0.0

Comment: Cual es el error en realidad? docker ps -a solo te muestra los procesos corriendo en tu pc

Comment: Según lo que leí, docker ps me muestra los procesos corriendo en mi pc, y docker ps -a me muestra los procesos que han sido detenidos. El problema es: ¿por qué se detiene el proceso?

Comment: Al igual el programa .NET que se ejecuta dura muy poco y cuando acaba de ejecutarse el contenedor Docker se para.

Comment: No, pueba con: docker container start myapp

Comment: No era que la ejecución del programa fuera breve, lo que sucedía es que el comando que aparece en la documentación de Docker, al menos a mi no me funcionó. Lo resolví usando uno que encontré en uno de los proyectos de GitHub que igual pertenecen a Docker.